# how to capture 2 elements and merge them?

Tags: java

I want to be able to capture the description from each room from my text file and store a whole description regardless of how many lines it has in one element.

Also stacks overflow isn't letingt me show how my text file is actually formatted
its actually like this:

ID = $

room =

Description:

exits:

**But without the empty lines seperating them**

**Code:**

```
package MiniTextBasedGame;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class fileParser {

    public static String[] getLines(File file){
        String contents = null;
        Path path = file.toPath();
        String[] lines = null;
        try {
            contents = Files.readString(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        lines = contents.split("\n");
        return lines;
    }
    public static void getRoomID(String[] array){
        ArrayList<String> arraylist= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
        ArrayList<String> idarraylist = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String str: arraylist) {
            if(str.contains("ID")){
               String temp = str.substring(5, 6);
               idarraylist.add(temp);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void getRoomName(String[] array){
        ArrayList<String> arraylist= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
        ArrayList<String> namearraylist = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String str: arraylist) {
            if(str.contains("name =")){
                String temp = str.substring(7);
                namearraylist.add(temp);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void getRoomDescription(String[] array){
        ArrayList<String> darray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
        ArrayList<String> tempArray = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String str: darray) {
            if (!(str.contains("ID") || str.contains("name =") || str.contains("Description:") || str.contains("exits"))) {
                if (!str.isBlank()) {
                    tempArray.add(str);
                }
            }
        }
        // Print out results
        for (String str: tempArray) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
    public static void getExits(String[] array){

    }
}
```

**Text File:**

```
ID = 0
name = Beginning 
Description: Y0ou are standing at the end of a road before a dark and dank cave. The forest is 
covering the road lending a dark and spooky aspect to the road. You hear a low wailing that 
seems to be coming from the cave. 
exits : East


ID = 1 
name = Room1 
Description: Y1ou are standing at the end of a
road before a dark and dank cave. The forest is covering the road
lending a dark and spooky aspect to the road. You hear a low wailing
that seems to be coming from the cave. exits : East, West, South

ID = 2 
name = Room2
Description: Y2ou are standing at the end of a
road before a dark and dank cave. The forest is covering the road
lending a dark and spooky aspect to the road. You hear a low wailing
that seems to be coming from the cave. 
exits : South, West

ID = 3
name = Room3 
Description: Y3ou are standing at the end of a
road before a dark and dank cave. The forest is covering the road
lending a dark and spooky aspect to the road. You hear a low wailing
that seems to be coming from the cave. 
exits : North, West

ID = 4
name = Room4 
Description: Y4ou are standing at the end of a
road before a dark and dank cave. The forest is covering the road
lending a dark and spooky aspect to the road. You hear a low wailing
that seems to be coming from the cave. 
exits : East, North, South

ID = 5 
name = End 
Description: Y5ou are standing at the end of a road
before a dark and dank cave. The forest is covering the road lending a
dark and spooky aspect to the road. You hear a low wailing that seems
to be coming from the cave. 
exits : North
```

Comment: What is the point of declaring a `ArrayList` in a method, adding to it, and not even returning it?

Comment: Possibly declare a `Room` class that has the fields you need (ID, Name, Description, Exits) and fill that just once.  Then return an ArrayList of Rooms.

Comment: Does your text file actually has explicit newline in Description? Or just one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better off use Regular Expression to parse your file. Here is an example regular expression that can extract information from your file:

`ID = ([0-9]+)\s*name = (.*)\s*Description: ([\s\S]+?)exits : (.*)`

https://regexr.com/64un0

To use it in Java:

```
    String str = Files.readString(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ID = ([0-9]+)\\s*name = (.*)\\s*Description: ([\\s\\S]+?)exits : (.*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while(m.find())
    {
        String id = m.group(1).trim();
        String name = m.group(2).trim();
        String description = m.group(3).trim();
        String exits = m.group(4).trim();
        //do the rest...
    }
```